# Windows 10 Start menu Downloads shortcut is broken

Tags: windows-10, download, shortcuts, start-menu

With a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro, I enabled Downloads shortcut to appear on Start menu. However when I click on it nothing happens. Other shortcuts such as Documents, Music etc all work fine. Is there a way I can fix this problem?
I suspect this issue is happening because I moved Downloads folder to another partition. "Quick access" shortcuts are fine it's just not accessible with Start menu.

I made a small gif/vid of what this is about:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/K2ny7ql.gifv]

Comment: I suggest you move the Downloads folder back to its original location to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Tried before no luck. But I assume original Downloads folder location is `C:\Users\$USER\Downloads`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix would be to open this folder:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu Places

Check if the "Downloads" shortcut exists. If it doesn't, restore it by running the SFC command, as below.

From elevated Command Prompt, type:

> sfc /scannow

Comment: There's no Downloads shortcut in that directory although other shortcuts exists. I created a shortcut but it didn't work. Also this is greyed out in start menu customisation settings http://i.imgur.com/3VikwHX.png

Comment: It's a shortcut (with a hash) and running `SFC /Scannow` would restore it back, provided the source copy itself isn't corrupted.

Comment: Try this command from elevated Command Prompt.

`sfc /scanfile="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu Places\03 - Documents.lnk"`

Comment: Thanks. Answer is now edited.. so that it will help others.